# tabbar goes up along with keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, tabbar

This has been posted before but no answers.

Problem:

`TabBar` --> (2 tabs)

- tab one has a `Scrollview` and an `EddiText`
- tab two: something else

When taping the `EditText`, the soft keyboard goes up and `TabBar` along with it.

(An ugly solution would be to disable scrolling in `ScrollView`)

Any decent solution to this?!

Comment: You may want to post a simple layout xml example for others to play with it. I'd expect it to be a wrong setting somewhere in the xml.

Comment: My code involves much more information than needed so it would be useless to do this. Anyone can make an exemaple it takes 2 minutes! Thanks

Comment: Hi Lukas, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution would be to tell the TabBar to adjust for Softkeyboard Mode. To do this, go to your manifest file, and in the Tabbar Activity add this line,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This makes your Tabbar to stay at the bottom even when the softkeyboard is visible.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Ignore answer, thought you were using Adobe Flex for Android (dont know why!!)**
This works, hides the tabbar on soft/virtual keyboard being activated, and makes it visible again when its deactivated.

The listeners could be added on a global application level http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=524.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        protected function textinput1_softKeyboardActivatingHandler(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.visible = false;
        }


        protected function textinput1_softKeyboardDeactivateHandler(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.visible = true;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Scroller id="scroller" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="70" >
    <s:VGroup paddingTop="3" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="3" horizontalAlign="center">

        <s:TextInput softKeyboardActivating="textinput1_softKeyboardActivatingHandler(event)"
                     softKeyboardDeactivate="textinput1_softKeyboardDeactivateHandler(event)"/>

    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```