# Don't want to hide EditText View when on EditText is pressed (After keyboard comeup) in Android?

Tags: android-layout, keyboard, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard

In Android Application,

when I pressed on EditText then it looks like as below :

[image]

I am using textview above tabbar and following code

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

in manifest file to hide tabs when EditText is pressed.But it also hides text view and button as below :

[image]

I dont want to hide textview , I just want to hide tabbar.

**xml file**

chatroom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <include layout="@layout/chat_tab_list" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

chat_tab_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:hint="@string/enter_text"
            android:inputType="text"                
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please Guide me on this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550878/tabbar-goes-up-along-with-keyboard) indicates that you should be able to just set the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the tab bar, but not on the text input. This way, the text input behaves normally, scrolling up, but the tab bar stays put. The text input should have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` so that it scrolls. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for details on the different modes.

Based on your edit, it looks like it's because your edit text is inside the tab widget. You should move the Edit Text outside into your root linearLayout with the soft input mode of adjustResize.

Comment: On Tabbar means:On TabHost or TabWidget ?Thanks.

Comment: @Ponting What did you try? i don't have an emulator up and running.

Comment: I put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in TabWidget ,android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in EditText and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in activity of Manifest file. When I pressed on EditText it hides TabBar and not hide keyboard as I want.But remaining screen also go upward side (Like ActionBar gone out of screen-upward side of the device)

Comment: @Ponting I updated my answer. You should move the EditText out of the tab widget into the root linearLayout

Answer (score 1):

try this

add this to your AndroidManifest just in activity who have your tab.

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried it.It didnt work.It also hide TextView along with TabBar.

Comment: please put your activity layout xml file

Comment: @Ponting  pls check if you add properly the tag to the TabActivityClass on your manifest file

Comment: which tag? I cant understand.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: I already tried that before posting question.It hides tab as well as textView.

Comment: No,I can't do that.If you wish then I can give you some of the files.

Comment: ok, try this then, remove tag "android:windowSoftInputMode" from Tabwidget and Textview and any where, then add it just to TabActivityClass in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Activity>
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 </Activity>
```