# In android, how to drop down edit text fields when a button is pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a button `Add new address` and when it is pressed, I want to show `EditText` fields to collect the new address details. Is there any layout to do that. Or hiding the text fields when the `Button` is unpressed, is that the only way to do this?

Comment: Just take edit-text and make it invisible and on button click event set it as visible.

Comment: Just follow this url :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458483/dont-want-to-hide-edittext-view-when-on-edittext-is-pressed-after-keyboard-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the edit box in a layout as below -

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/exp_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/exp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

       />

</LinearLayout>
```

And now use the layout id to get the view like below.

```
LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.exp_linear_layout);
```

And just toggle the visibility on button click event -

```
l.setVisibility(View.GONE) and vice versa.
```

I hope it will help u.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in framework to do it. You can do this by setting `View.SetVisibility()` to visible or gone. Initially the button is visible but textfield is invisible. When user click on the button, you can set this button visibility invisible or gone and visible the text fields.